# Is it possible to check nvcc compilation with autoconf?

Tags: c, cuda, autoconf, nvcc

I am trying to test some typical cuda functions during the configure process. How can I write it in my configure.ac? Something like:

```
AC_TRY_COMPILE([],
[
__global__ static void test_cuda() {
    const int tid = threadIdx.x;
    const int bid = blockIdx.x;
    __syncthreads();
}
],
[cuda_comp=ok],[cuda_comp=no])
```

But nvcc is not defined in AC_LANG. Must I create my own m4 macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am highly doubtful whether it is possible to cleanly hook into the AC_LANG, AC_TRY_COMPILE etc. series of macros without actually rewriting parts of autoconf.

The safe bet for you is to just write a test. Unless you need that test in several projects, you do not even need to wrap the test in m4 macros.

The test would first check for `nvcc`, then create some test source file and finally try compiling that using `$NVCC`. Then it needs to examine the results of the compilation (return code and generated files), and finally to clean up any files it might have generated.

Something like

```
AC_ARG_VAR([NVCC], [nvcc compiler to use])
AC_PATH_PROG([NVCC], [nvcc], [no])
working_nvcc=no
if test "x$NVCC" != "xno"
the
    AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether nvcc works])
    cat>conftest.c<<EOF
    __global__ whatever() {
       ...
    }
EOF
    if $NVCC conftest.c && test_whether_output_files_are_ok
    then
        working_nvcc=yes
    fi
    rm -f conftest.c conftest.o conftest.what conftest.ever
    AC_MSG_RESULT([$working_nvcc])
fi
AM_CONDITIONAL([WORKING_NVCC], [test "x$working_nvcc" = "xyes"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is more a general autotools answer, but it is exactly what I need.